# Floating Div Causing Trouble

Tags: jquery, html, responsive, floating, hamburger-menu

I seem to have gotten into a peculiar problem with a floating div. The example of the div is at [this website](http://nimbus.interactiveworld.in/the-hyde-park.html)

What i am unable to accomplish is to convert the menu contained in the div into a responsive stackable burger menu.

I'll really appreciate your help on this.

Best wishes,
Sumit

Answer (score 0):

You hide the large menu, and show the stackable burger, on small screen. This can be done by using just CSS.

[Mobile first](https://www.google.co.id/search?q=mobile+first), so basically:

```
.largeMenuDiv { display: none }

@media ( min-width: 480px ) {

    .largeMenuDiv    { display: block; }
    .stackableBurger { display: none; }

}
```

Of course you can JavaScript the menu to morph on different screen sizes, but it's more complicated IMO.

Comment: Thanks rlatief, however, i am unable to trigger the code on the div id floatdiv_1907 which i understand houses the left floating menu. Technically, I need two stacks - main menu which works fine as of now and scrolls with the page, title of the page below that which also works fine. The new burger menu that houses the floating div which is where the issue is. This can continue to float on the left hand side.